# android action bar add back button and searchView issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I hava a `ActionBar` which show only option button on it like as

[image]

now I want to add back button and `SearchView` on it how can I add these button on `ActionBar`?

this is my activity code..

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `Toolbar` and `AppCompatActivity`

How to use `ToolBar` you can see at this [Demo](https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm)

Use must have to add these item in menu file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

use this in you `Activity` class

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

See this link for [android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for `ToolBar` and style for material